# how to get tap events in a text using core text framework in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, uitouch, core-text

i am doing a reader application in IPAD ,the book data is stored in Sqlite DB,i render this content of DB in a view through core text...the formate of my text is like this e.g.:1 haii this is iPhone. 2 this is iPad. 3 this is mac. etc etc..i just want to get touch events while touching the text.for example if i tap the first sentence,,the fist sentence only must be selected with any color,and trigger a popup(subview or alert view or action sheet)like the image below[image]

i am having this code to make the text to shown in a view

```
NSMutableString *combined = [NSMutableString string];

    for(NSUInteger idx = 0; idx < [delegatee.allSelectedVerseEnglish count]; idx++) {
        [combined appendFormat:@"  %d %@", 
         idx + 1, 
         [delegatee.allSelectedVerseEnglish objectAtIndex:idx]];

    }

    self.multiPageView.text =combined;
```

`combined` is the string contains verses oif the bible of the selected chapter,so when i click the first verse it need to be selected like the image below and pops up a subview or alert view like the image below,and by selection that verse must be stored in somewhere or copy to clipboard.`multiPageView` is the view that render the core text .i want just like in olive tree bible application or ibook.

i am not using the web view,due to some limitation in the web view..is there any idea how to do this..,please help me.
Thanks in advance.
EDIT:

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{

    mainpopupview.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004)    ;
    [self.view addSubview:mainpopupview];

    NSRange selectedRange = [textView selectedRange];
    NSString *backString = [maintextview.text substringToIndex:selectedRange.location];
    NSRange backRange = [backString rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    NSRange backRangee = [backString rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    int  myRangeLenght = backRangee.location - backRange.location;
    NSRange myStringRange = NSMakeRange (backRange.location, myRangeLenght);
    NSString *forwardString  = [maintextview.text substringFromIndex:backRange.location];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[forwardString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:1]);
    NSLog (@"%@",  [maintextview.text substringWithRange:myStringRange]);

    NSString * myStringTxt = [[forwardString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"1 %@", myStringTxt);

      //  maintextview.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    NSRange myStringRangee = [maintextview.text rangeOfString:myStringTxt];
    [maintextview select:self];
    maintextview.selectedRange = myStringRangee;
    }
```

myStringTxt contains the correct verse(menz text between .to .but i want to elect this text.

Comment: what class is multiPageView? is it a UILabel, a UITextView, or is it really using CoreText?

Comment: @jasongregori haii,it its really using CoreText.am using aksomocoretextwrapper http://akosma.com/2010/07/08/core-text-objective-c-wrapper/  class to render the text to my main view

Comment: are you using `AKOMultiColumnTextView` or `AKOMultiPageTextView`?

Comment: yeah that wont work. @vignesh thought you were using a `UITextView` but you aren't. What class are you using specifically?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11500/discussion-between-stackiphone-and-jasongregori)

Comment: @vignesh - I am trying to do something similar. I would appreciate your help!

Comment: @stackiphone - I am trying to do something similar. I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can wire up UITextview's `UIControlEventEditingChanged` to some method. So when ever the user selects something that method would be called. Inside the method you can obtain the selected text using,

```
NSRange range = [txtView selectedRange];
NSString *str = [txtView.text substringWithRange:range];
```

From the selected string you can perform the actions you like.

If your text view is editable you can get,

```
NSLog(@"%d",range.location);
```

Once you know the location you can create a range and select string. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668652/iphone-selectedrange-for-a-non-editable-uitextview-or-other-methods-of-click) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982453/make-uitextview-react-to-tap-event-iphone) has relevant info.

> //Here is the complete sample code.

```
  {
        sampleTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 60, 300)];
        sampleTextView.text = @"This is sample text to find text under touch. I am not going to use any private api.How am i supposed to do?.Let me see.";
        sampleTextView.editable = YES;
        sampleTextView.delegate = (id)self;
        [self.view addSubview:sampleTextView];
    }
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:sampleTextView   selector:@selector(resignFirstResponder) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSRange selectedRange = [textView selectedRange];
    NSString *backString = [sampleTextView.text substringToIndex:selectedRange.location];
    NSRange backRange = [backString rangeOfString:@" " options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    NSString *forwardString  = [sampleTextView.text substringFromIndex:backRange.location];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[forwardString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:1]);
}
```

EDIT :

I have updated the code based on your requirement. Please find it below,

```
UITextView *textview;
BOOL toggle;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    textview = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
    textview.delegate = (id)self;
    textview.inputView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    textview.text = @"Let's hope the text selection works programmatically!";
    [self.view addSubview:textview];
}

- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
{    
    NSRange selectedRange = [textView selectedRange];
    NSString *backString = [textView.text substringToIndex:selectedRange.location];
    NSRange backRange = [backString rangeOfString:@" " options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    NSString *forwardString  = [textView.text substringFromIndex:backRange.location];

    NSLog(@"%@",[[forwardString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:1]);

    NSRange ran = [textView.text rangeOfString:[[forwardString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:1]];

    if (!toggle)
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(selectText:) withObject:[NSValue valueWithRange:ran] afterDelay:0.001];
    }
    else
    {
        toggle = !toggle;
    }
}

-(void)selectText:(NSValue *)sender
{
    toggle = !toggle;

    textview.selectedRange = [sender rangeValue];
}
```

Comment: haii thanks for your response,,i didn't understand what u said...i ahem tons of sentences ,its a bible app,so if the user tap any sentence,,it want to highlight that sentence only and trigger a action,,like the above image..

Comment: OK. Actually there are two parts in your question.1) Selecting the text 2)bring popover on selection. I have addressed only the second part. Let me try the first part.

Comment: ,i tried it,but it say my view controller oenott support selected range,becz am using core text which render text to a view controller.any idea?>

Comment: haii vigneshh,i changes my core text framework and instead of that i put UITextview ,your code works for me..but some doubts there.

Comment: @stackiphone. Glad it is of some help!.

Comment: how can i calculate the string range from the above code?i got the correct verse when i tapped,but i need the selection also for the tapped verse.

Comment: can u please please help me to solve this issue?i tried my maximum but no luck.didnt get the selection of the tapped verese.i will give you 100 bounty for it

Comment: @stackiphone. No prob about bounty.I don answer for that:) I am little busy. Thats'y not replying promptly. Let me know the issue. I will try !.

Comment: ohh thats great.i am getting the correct verse when i tapped ,just change you this line of code   NSRange backRange = [backString rangeOfString:@" " options:NSBackwardsSearch]; to   NSRange backRange = [backString rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch]; but i want to select that verse like the default opt select  of textview.

Comment: if you became free,plz look into my edited portion of the question,i tried that much with the help of your code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11618/discussion-between-stackiphone-and-vignesh)

Comment: ,i tried lott,but no luck textview dideditend didn't seems to be work,but there is in built nsselect range in EGOTextview.i think its possible in EGO ,but due to my lack of deep knlowdge i am not able to do it.

Comment: ,i am trying with EGOTextView,it has the selection highlighting property also,we can change any color to highlight the selection,but it only select the single word.

Comment: new solution highlight too.try that.

Comment: ohh you given anew one ,i dint noticed it.thats let me try

Comment: i give you 100 bounty,if the solution works or not,becz i am getting the verse correctly becz of your code.let me chk

Comment: @stackiphone. Ha, you gave it?.Thanks:) .

Comment: i have doubt,where id i put this code UITextView *textview;
BOOL toggle;?my textview is maintextview.so is it necessary to add this code UITextView *textview;.

Comment: brillient,,this is brilliancy.i never forgot this help....so you deserves that bounty..thanks man

Comment: @stackiphone.  Glad it is of some help!:)

Comment: not some help,it helps me lotto...now searching for dismissing of the keyboard...from thgis view,the selection is ok,but the keyboard is there in the view.hehehe.i just ask a question about this now.

Comment: @stackiphone. Just saw it!. Let me explain.